# Conversion of CURL to Python requests Elastic search

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, curl, python-requests

I have following curl command for elastic search:

```
curl -XGET "http://my_host.net:9200/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' { "query": { "match_all": {} } }'
```

I tried to convert it to python's requests equivalent using https://curl.trillworks.com/. But I am getting 405 as response.

My python converted code is as follows:

```
    import requests
    data = ' { "query": { "match_all": {} } }'

    response = requests.post('http://my_host.net:9200/_search -H', data=data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the `-H` from the URL in your `post` call and also add the `Content-type` header to the call:

```
import requests
data = ' { "query": { "match_all": {} } }'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.post('http://my_host.net:9200/_search', data=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: It worked. but I am confused as my curl was a Get request, but it converted to post. How can I make Get call out of this ?

Comment: use `requests.get`... although note that sending a body using GET might not be working as you expect.